# Handle Ui for all screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

If i have specific layout which contains 2 ui components Application logo image and edit text, and i want to handle this layout for all screen sizes beginning from 2 inches to 10 inches.

I have taken a decision to stretch the layout components for high sizes and shrink it for small sizes, but i have some issues

1- How to test this layout to assure if it fits on all screen sizes, do i have to create at least one emulator for every group of inches ?

2- how I stretch the image view, shall i create dimensions for it for every group of inches?

3 - Application logo when i stretch it for higher screen sizes (7 and 10 inches) it get distorted and pixelated , what i have to do with this image, do i have to export app logo for every group of inches ?

Answer (score 0):

Same application Logo should not be used for all resolutions. We need to place images with respective resolution in respective folders like
Lower resolution images in drawable-ldpi 
Higher resolution images in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi. Android OS takes care of selecting the image from respective folder based on the device screen resolution.

In order to test you can use an easier way i.e., in the Graphical Layout at the top there is a drop down with the last option as "Preview All Screens" where you can have a glance how is your design in all resolutions

Comment: I am talking about handling app logo fot different screen sizes not for different screen resolutions